# jQuery Ajax raising TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having quite a hard time to figure this out. I would like to know if `TypeError` is caused by the second AJAX call (or the `osmtogeojson.js`)?

I made sure that my data in the first success function is not null by alerting it.

```
function sendQueryData(url, query){
    url =url.replace('query' , query);

    if (query === ""){
        alert("City Input Required");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
          },
          type: "POST",
          url: "/search/pass/",
          data: {
              'query' : query
          },
          success: function(data){
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json;  charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'feature': osmtogeojson(data)
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = url
                }
            });
          }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the what the browser console outputs:

> TypeError: e.elements is undefined
>
> [Learn More]
>      osmtogeojson.js:4:2503
>
> n http://localhost:8000/static/js/osmtogeojson.js:4:2503
>
> u http://localhost:8000/static/js/osmtogeojson.js:4:14818
>
> success http://localhost:8000/:235:36
>
> i https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1
>   /jquery.min.js:2:28012
>
> firewith https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:28783
>
> A https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:14033
>
> c/< https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:16323

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your script using developer tools then see in the call stack to properly pin point the problem. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @Pratansyah I'll try this since I'm not really that skilled yet in javascript

Comment: I think the error is in the `osmtogeojson()` function not shown.

Comment: @nnnnnn I see alright better to raise this in their git if so.

Comment: Well it may be that the `data` object you pass that function doesn't have the expected structure. Consult their documentation to double-check that before raising issues.

Comment: @nnnnnn that may be unlikely. before this ajax I have a separate function that calls the it the same way and it properly gets it. So I assumed just now that "maybe" because I have two instances of it in the same file. So I tried creating a global variable instead and whatever output it has I stored there and use it at my second ajax in this function instead and it works. So yeah raising this in their repo.

Comment: To send `contentType: 'application/json;` you don't pass an object to `data` ...all the data must be json

Comment: @charlietfl osmtogeojson actually is a javascript that converts an object to geojson/json. even if I create a var outside of `data` to convert it, it creates an error.

Comment: Fine but once you resolve that you would need to concatenate it into your data json string if you plan to send other fields also like `feature`

Comment: @charlietfl noted. might have to use JSON.stringify(data) by that time if I'm correct :)